# How to write a DML to update a field in a table based on a field of another table?

Tags: oracle

Suppose there are two tables 'A' and 'B'. A ( F1 number, F2 number ) and B ( F1 number, F2 number ). I want a dml to do this :-

All rows where A.F1 = B.F1, set A.F2 = B.F2.

(i.e.)

> if A : [(1,34)(2,67)]    B :
>   [(1,99)(2,100)]
>
> DML should update A to following:
>
> A : [(1,99)(2,100)]

Thanks in advance !

Trinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a correlated update

```
UPDATE a
   SET f2 = (SELECT f2
               FROM b
              WHERE a.f1 = b.f1)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM b
     WHERE a.f1 = b.f1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it possible for the DML to be shorter.. may be using "with" clause ?

Comment: @trinity - What do you mean by "shorter"?  If you can guarantee that every row in A has a matching row in B, you can eliminate the WHERE clause.  But I don't see how using the WITH clause would simplify the query at all.